# Git: hook on git pull whether merge or not

Tags: git, hook

I use the "post-merge" git hook but when there is nothing to merge, the hook is not executed.

Which hook should I use to be executed on pulls, whether there is a merge or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hook for `git pull`.

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8747884/6309), you would need to set up some kind of task monitoring the new commits being fetched into the local repo in order to trigger what you want.
That or an [alias for the `git pull` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11225689/6309).